MsalUiRequiredException: An error occured during token acquisition: No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call
I have a problem with the login and don't know what to do.
I'm pretty sure it has to do with my program.cs:
using MudBlazor.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;
using Serilog;
using System.Configuration;


internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .CreateBootstrapLogger();
        Log.Information("App started");

        builder.Host.UseSerilog((ctx, lc) => lc
            .MinimumLevel.Information()
            .WriteTo.Console());

        builder.Logging.AddConsole();

        //adding dbContext

        string[]? initialScopes = builder.Configuration["DownstreamApi:Scopes"]?.Split(' ') ?? builder.Configuration["MicrosoftGraph:Scopes"]?.Split(' ');
        builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
                    .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
                    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

        builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

        builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
        });

        builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
        builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor()
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();

        builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
            .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

        builder.Services.AddMudServices(config =>
        {
            config.SnackbarConfiguration.PositionClass = MudBlazor.Defaults.Classes.Position.TopCenter;
            config.SnackbarConfiguration.PreventDuplicates = true;
            config.SnackbarConfiguration.NewestOnTop = false;
            config.SnackbarConfiguration.ShowCloseIcon = true;
            config.SnackbarConfiguration.RequireInteraction = true;
            config.SnackbarConfiguration.HideTransitionDuration = 300;
            config.SnackbarConfiguration.ShowTransitionDuration = 300;
            config.SnackbarConfiguration.SnackbarVariant = MudBlazor.Variant.Filled;
        });

        builder.Services.AddMudBlazorDialog();

        //Adding my services


        var app = builder.Build();

        if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseAntiforgery();

        app.MapControllers();
        app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
            .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();
        app.Run();
    }
}

Every time I start my app, I get this error the first time:
[MsIdWeb] An error occured during token acquisition: No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call.
But the login instantly works because it retries. I just don't know what to do about this, I think I can't add claims to the logged in user because the user is null at first.
In the beginning, I ignored the error, because the login still worked instantly and I had no issues but when I tried to add claims the other day, the page was just stuck instantly and according to the logs the app attempts a new login every time the user is null.
I tried multiple different methods instead of AddAuthentication, no luck.
Another thing I tried, is the manual re-login, when the MsalUiRequiredException pops us, it just forces me to login. I removed it again tho, because this would happen every time I would open the site.

I had this error message when the auzre configuration doesn't have the downstream api scope. You could check if you have all the follwoing in appsettings.json.
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "xxx.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "xxxx",
    "ClientId": "xxxx",
    "ClientSecret": "xxxx",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "Scopes": "api://85a8853a-64c7-4023-ae90-7f709bfc3bb4/access_as_user"
  },

Make sure the "front web app" include the scope of "back end exposed api"

When calling back-end api:
            string[] scopes = new string[] { "api://85a8853a-64c7-4023-ae90-7f709bfc3bb4/access_as_user" };
            string accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes);

            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
            var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:7299/weatherforecast");


Hi @Qiang Fu, I created the api, but where do I put the code for the backend api? I don't know where to call it.

@kas It is acutally the "on-behalf-of" flow of azure ad. (front mvc and back api both protected by aad, then mvc can call backend with access token.) I can write a detailed steps of small sample later.

I think I have a different problem tho. I tried to use ur approach inside of my FakeAuthenticationStateProvider, but I get the user is null exception when I try to get the token.

@kas what global rendermode are you using? Do you use interactiveServer with disable prerender?

I'm using InteractiveServer.
